# UITableView - Reposition Cells after Header Height change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

#### Problem

tableView does not reposition cells correctly after tableHeaderView height change.

#### Desired Outcome

after pressing a button, the tableHeaderView changes height, and correctly repositions cells.

#### Important Code

- Changes height on tap - end of configureRxSwift()
- Initialization of tableView - initTableView() & initTableHeader()

#### Current Outcome

[image]
[image]

#### Full code

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import SnapKit

class AthleteSearchController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var shouldShowSearchResults = false
    var schoolID = ""
    var sportMode = ""
    let selectedAthlete = PublishSubject<JSON>()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let filterButton = UIButton()
    let tableHeaderView = UIView()
    let filterView = UIView()
    let searchView = UIView()

    var filterShown = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initUI()
        configureRxSwift()
    }
    func initUI() {
        initTableView()
        initTableHeader()
        initSearchView()
        initSearchBar()
        initFilterButton()
        initFilterView()
    }
    func initTableHeader() {
        tableHeaderView.addSubview(filterView)
        tableHeaderView.addSubview(searchView)

        tableHeaderView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(self.tableView.snp.width)
            make.height.equalTo(50)
        }

    }
    func initSearchView() {
        searchView.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchView.addSubview(filterButton)
        searchView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(50)
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    func initFilterButton() {
        filterButton.setTitle("Filter", for: .normal)
        filterButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.bottom.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalTo(70)
        }
    }
    func initFilterView() {
        filterView.backgroundColor = .red
        filterView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(searchView.snp.bottom)
            make.bottom.width.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    func initSearchBar() {
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for an athlete here..."

        searchBar.delegate = nil
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.right.equalTo(self.filterButton.snp.left)
        }
    }

    func initTableView() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = nil
        tableView.delegate = nil
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)

        }
        tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    func configureRxSwift() {

        let url = "https://www.athletic.net/\(self.sportMode)/School.aspx?SchoolID=\(self.schoolID)"
        let allAthletes = dataRequest(url: url).map {
            $0[1]["athletes"].arrayValue
        }
        let searchFilter = self.searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()

        Observable.combineLatest(allAthletes, searchFilter) { athletes, text in
            text.isEmpty ? athletes : athletes.filter {
                $0["Name"].stringValue.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
        }.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = element["Name"].stringValue
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        self.tableView.rx.modelSelected(JSON.self)
            .debug("selectedAthlete")
            .take(1)
            .bind(to: self.selectedAthlete)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        // Updates Height
        filterButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
        self.tableHeaderView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            if (self.filterShown) {
                make.height.equalTo(50)
            } else {
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
            self.filterShown.toggle()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableHeaderView
        }
        })

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.selectedAthlete.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reload the table view after changing header height:

```swift
self.tableHeaderView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
    if (self.filterShown) {
        make.height.equalTo(50)
    } else {
        make.height.equalTo(100)
    }
    self.filterShown.toggle()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableHeaderView
    self.tableView.reloadData() // <- add this
}
```

Comment: this adds some very weird behavior, and does not completely resolve the issue.